# Ionic Framework Center button within ionic item

Tags: ionic-framework, button

I am using ionic framework. The following code make the buttons align left. I would like to make the buttons align center. How can I do that ? Thanks

```
<ion-list>    
  <ion-item><button ion-button (click)="gotoPage1();">Go page 1</button></ion-item>
  <ion-item><button ion-button (click)="gotoPage2()">Go page 2</button></ion-item>
  <ion-item><button ion-button (click)="gotoPage3()">Go page 3</button></ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ionic provides a set of utility attributes that can be used on any element in order to modify the text or adjust the padding or margin.

**[Read - Ionic CSS Utilities](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/)**

you can use `text-center`

> The inline contents are centered within the line box.

**Try like this'**

```
<ion-list >    
  <ion-item  text-center ><button ion-button (click)="gotoPage1(); ">Go page 1</button></ion-item>
  <ion-item text-center><button ion-button (click)="gotoPage2()">Go page 2</button></ion-item>
  <ion-item text-center><button ion-button (click)="gotoPage3()">Go page 3</button></ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

[stackblitz - code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-lebmk3)

Answer (score 3):

The current answer (Ionic 4) requires that in addition to using text-center, your wrap the buttons in a label.  This works correctly:

```
<ion-list>    
  <ion-item text-center>
    <ion-label>
      <ion-button (click)="gotoPage1();">Go page 1</ion-button>
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item text-center>
    <ion-label>
      <ion-button (click)="gotoPage2();">Go page 2</ion-button>
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item text-center>
    <ion-label>
      <ion-button (click)="gotoPage3();">Go page 3</ion-button>
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ionic's `text-center` CSS Utility. See https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/

**Example Usage:**

```
<ion-item text-center>
  <button ion-button>click me</button>
</ion-item>
```

If you don't want the whole item content to be centered you can use css to center just the button.

e.g. wrapping the button with a **text-center** wrapper div inside the `ion-item`

Comment: Hi text-center doesn't work. If I change the button to fix length using CSS.                                                                                  .homeBtn {
  display:block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  /* border-radius: 50%; */
  border: 1px ;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  
}                                                                                          <ion-item text-center>
  <button ion-button class="homeBtn">click me</button>
</ion-item>

Answer (score 0):

Ionic Framework Center button within ionic item
I used this method

```
<ion-grid>
       <ion-row>
         <ion-col size="12" class="ion-text-center">
          <ion-button>
            Login
          </ion-button>
         </ion-col>
       </ion-row>
   </ion-grid>
```