# Ionic how to center items wrapped with Ion-Item

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have searched quite a bit and tried and tried but I can't figure out how to center ionic elements that are wrapped with `<Ion-Item></Ion-Item>`.

Here are some suggestions I've looked at and none of them work:

[Ionic Framework Center button within ionic item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53092411/ionic-framework-center-button-within-ionic-item)

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17509

Here is one that works, but it is basically doing away with the `<ion-item>` wrapping. The issue described here is basically what I am also having trouble with.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-center-a-ion-icon-inside-a-ion-item-ionic-4/158400

For example I have the following which does exactly what I want, which is to center the buttons on the screen, but again, that is without using `<ion-item>`.

```
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-button size="small" [routerLink]="['/someplace', itemId, item.resultId]">Edit</ion-button>
        <ion-button size="small" color="danger" (click)="onDelete(itemId, item.resultId)">Delete</ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

However, as soon as I wrap my buttons with `<Ion-Item></Ion-Item>` it aligns the buttons to the left and no matter what I try I cannot center align my buttons.  I'm wrapping my buttons and most of my ionic elements with `<ion-item></ion-item>` because that seems to be the recommendation.  So how do I do that and still have control over the alignment of the contents wrapped with `<ion-item>`.

Here is what is not working:

```
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-item>
        <ion-button size="small" [routerLink]="['/someplace', itemId, item.resultId]">Edit</ion-button>
        <ion-button size="small" color="danger" (click)="onDelete(itemId, item.resultId)">Delete</ion-button>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of class "ion-text-center".

```
<ion-item class="ion-text-center">
    <ion-button size="small" [routerLink]="['/someplace', itemId, item.resultId]">Edit</ion-button>
    <ion-button size="small" color="danger" (click)="onDelete(itemId, item.resultId)">Delete</ion-button>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: This only works if you wrap each<ion-button> element inside its own <ion-label> element.  The reason is the the class "ion-text-center" only applies to text elements, and an <ion-button> is not a piece of text.  But by putting <ion-button> inside of <ion-label> it becomes a textual element, and therefore subject to the class="ion-text-center" class.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for a solution for this for quite a while as well. I could not find a way to center ion items without wrapping the text in h tags or p tags and styling those. I removed my ion items and then set my content to be centered based on their width ratios:

for things like an ion-textarea I set these css properties to center them

```
ion-textarea{
max-width: 80vw;
margin-left: 10vw;
}
```

This ratio of width and margin also worked on buttons within ion-items but I have yet to find how to center ion-item content themselves. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I will advise using `ion-row` when dealing with complex components like the ion button or a group of them. The takehome is set the `class="ion-justify-content-center"` on the `ion-row` and a `size` for the `ion-col`.

```js
<ion-row class="ion-justify-content-center">
  <ion-col size="sm">
    <ion-button (click)="logout()" size="small">
      <ion-icon
        slot="start"
        class="ion-padding-end"
        name="log-out-outline"
      ></ion-icon>
      Logout
    </ion-button>
    <ion-button (click)="login()" size="small">
      <ion-icon
        slot="start"
        class="ion-padding-end"
        name="log-in-outline"
      ></ion-icon>
      Login
    </ion-button>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

If we are interested in centring only texts, then [@Sourabh Chopade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9092893/sourabh-chopade) answer will be ideal.